# How to save Lists of Lists (List<List<String>> list) in JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I am using Spring server and JPA to save the variables.

I am trying to save:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    List<List<String>> Listarespostas = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

But obviously an error appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class palmaslab.mapas.config.Application: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
    at palmaslab.mapas.config.Application.main(Application.java:54)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1225)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:853)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:150)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: Project_Listarespostas, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(Listarespostas)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Collection.validate(Collection.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1362)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1849)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
```

Anyone knows an alternative?

Comment: Use an entity that contains the inner list as an element collection and then make the outer list a list of those entities.

Comment: @Thomas do you think i have to create a `@Repository interface innerlistRepository extends CrudRepository<innerlist,Long>`  ?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know Spring that well so I'm not sure here. The doc, however, indicates that `CrudRepository` helps for queries etc. but you'd first need to build your model in a way that JPA understands.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To cut to the chase, you simply can't do it.

The `@ElementCollection` annotation expects a collection of embeddable types. This will be simply translated to a child table having a FK reference to the parent entity.

So the `Embeddable` maps the child SQL table columns. A List<?> can't be an embeddable.

Because you cannot nest collections of embeddable types:

> An embeddable class (including an embeddable class within another
> embeddable class) that is contained within an element collection must
> not contain an element collection, nor may it contain a relationship
> to an entity other than a many-to-one or one-to-one relationship. The
> embeddable class must be on the owning side of such a relationship and
> the relationship must be mapped by a foreign key mapping. (See Section
> 2.9.)

What you can do is to create a new entity type `Child` that has a List<?> instead.

So the parent child embedable list becomes:

```
@OneToMany
List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

Where the `Child` looks like:

```
@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    List<String> children = new ArrayList<>();
}
```